# Green formula and Gauss formula in real analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Most real analysis book only talk about the relation between Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral in $[a,b]$, [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Real_Analysis/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Calculus) and Fubini theorem, no real analysis books I have read talk about Green formula and Gauss formula. So my question is what is the Green formula and Gauss formula in real analysis, is it the same as what we have learnt in calculus?

Comment: You may want to get a book in differential geometry instead. Oh and I think you mean Stoke's Theorem, which is generalization of Green. The real Stoke's Theorem work with *manifolds*, not just surfaces and in fact generalizes the FTC.

Comment: You should take a look at Calculus of Vector Functions Richard E. Williamson, it has an simple approach to this on chapter 7

Comment: @Nameless I think *you* mean Stokes' theorem.  It's named after George Stokes (although he didn't actually find the result).